# How to safely use iOS advertisingIdentifier?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/adsupport/asidentifiermanager/1614148-isadvertisingtrackingenabled):

> Check the value of this property before performing any advertising tracking. If the value is `false`, use the advertising identifier only for the following purposes: frequency capping, attribution, conversion events, estimating the number of unique users, advertising fraud detection, and debugging.

So based on that, the code below should work safely and be following Apple's documentation:

```
var advertisingID: String? {
    if ASIdentifierManager.shared().isAdvertisingTrackingEnabled == true {
        return nil
    } else {
        return ASIdentifierManager.shared().advertisingIdentifier.uuidString
    }
}
```

Basically checking to see if it's false, then, if so using it. Of course that code could be simplified, but I'm trying to be as verbose as possible for this question.

That code seems correct to me according to Apple's documentation.

That being said, it doesn't fit the name of the property really, nor does it fit open source projects on GitHub.

Below are a few open source projects with links that do it a different way.

[DeviceInfo](https://github.com/marumemomo/DeviceInfo/blob/bddcfb42849189a8fc7d452ea9798a9b5be1bd60/DeviceInfo/DeviceInfo.swift#L59):

```
return ASIdentifierManager.shared().isAdvertisingTrackingEnabled ? ASIdentifierManager.shared().advertisingIdentifier.uuidString : ""
```

[drifter](https://github.com/wenerme/drifter/blob/aea35f9131071971c923e8b418c96c9d668db8f6/ios/Classes/SwiftDrifterPlugin.swift#L35-L40):

```
// Check whether advertising tracking is enabled
guard ASIdentifierManager.shared().isAdvertisingTrackingEnabled else {
    return nil
}
// Get and return IDFA
return ASIdentifierManager.shared().advertisingIdentifier.uuidString
```

As you can see, instead of returning that value if it's `false` these solutions return the `advertisingIdentifier` if `isAdvertisingTrackingEnabled` is `true`. Which is not what Apple's documentation states. But it does make sense given the property name.

---

So my question is, which is correct? Is Apple's documentation wrong? Or are these open source projects doing it incorrectly? Or am I just missing something obvious and both those open source projects and Apple's documentation are both correct?

Comment: Well, they all look the same to me. What's the problem with the libs approach?

Comment: @paivaalan How are they the same? The libraries are returning the value if `isAdvertisingTrackingEnabled` is true. The code I wrote just now based on Apple's documentation returns the value if `isAdvertisingTrackingEnabled` is false. True vs false, big difference, not the same at all.

Comment: Yeah yeah, just misread. Check my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can do all of that if the value is `false`. But the common usage, which is for ad targeting, should only be done if value is `true`. Therefore, libraries approach is correct.

Comment: So then why on this [page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/adsupport/asidentifiermanager/1614151-advertisingidentifier) does it say "In iOS 10.0 and later, the value of advertisingIdentifier is all zeroes when the user has limited ad tracking.". Your answer makes it sound like that value will be accessible no matter what the boolean value is.

Comment: The thing is it really goes to all zeroes, but nothing prevents you from storing that value somehow (which ideally you also shouldn't). I think this is really straightforward. When `isAdvertisingTrackingEnabled` is true, `uuidString` is something other that all zeroes and you can use it for ad tracking. Otherwise `uuidString` is all zeroes and you shouldn't use old value if you have it stored. Also, user can reset advertisement identifier, so don't store it.

Comment: Ok, well then Apple shouldn't be saying `false` in their documentation. That is just plain wrong then. When submitting your app for review Apple asks you specific questions about your implementation around this feature. They are very strict about use of this feature. Which is why at the very least it's very misleading. Your answer kinda contradicts what Apple says. Which I'm not saying is wrong. But I am ensuring that we are on the same page.

Comment: Well, that's a bit subject, but for me it clearly states what I said. It says to check the value before performing ad tracking. Otherwise (i.e. `false` value) you can do only those other things. Summarizing, respect the user privacy specially if you're sending that value to third parties.

Comment: `and honors a user's Limit Ad Tracking setting in iOS and, when it is enabled by a user, this app does not use Advertising Identifier, and any information obtained through the user of the Advertising Identifier`, https://techcrunch.com/2014/04/11/apple-developers-must-now-agree-to-ad-identifier-rules-or-risk-app-store-rejection/. I'm sorry, but I think the reality is that if it's false you aren't allowed to do access it, and it's true you are ONLY allowed to do those things. OR visa versa. The question is, which one is it. Are you allowed to access it when it's true or false?

Comment: When Limit Ad Tracking = true -> isAdvertisingTrackingEnabled = false. Therefore, all that said above.